# Mapbox GL JS - Data Driven Styling - Finding Min & Max or Range of Data in a Layer

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-js

I am using data driven styling to create choropleth maps, with the ability to use a dropdown to select a different field and change the `property` within `'fill-color'` when styling `'paint'` of a layer.

The problem is, the `stops` for each layer involve a different min and max value, and therefore selecting a different field/property requires a re-definition of the min & max in `stops` to get a proper choropleth.

Is there a built-in solution to pull the min / max values from within a particular field in a layer?

Answer (score 0):

I'm happy to hear you're building cool things with data-driven styling in GL JS.

There is no built-in solution to pull the min / max values from within a particular field in a layer. This is an unfortunate technical limitation. If you were to have a 1TB vector tile set that spans the whole world, we would need to download all 1TB of data to find the min / max values.

Some options you have:

- If you're sourcing data from a GeoJSON file, you can parse it yourself to find the min / max values
- If you only care about data visible within the current viewport you can use `querySourceFeatures` to get all values and parse it yourself to find the min / max values
- If you're willing to do some sleuthing and use an undocumented Mapbox-specific API, we have an API that'll give you data about min / max values within an uploaded tile set.

Comment: Lucas, thanks for the reply! The dataset in question is indeed an uploaded tileset. Can you elaborate on your third option? Also related to streamlining these changing of choropleths - is setPaintProperty able to change a 'property' value within 'fill-color'?

Comment: @lucas-wojciechowski I am also interested in using the API for this exact purpose. I've got as far as [TileJSON metadata](https://www.mapbox.com/api-documentation/#retrieve-tilejson-metadata) but this doesn't contain much regarding the range of values. Can you please point us in the direction of the undocumented bits?